# Create an array of last 12 months including month and year based on an input Month/Year in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to create an array of the last 12 months (Month/Year in "mmm-yy" format) based on Month/Year in "mmm-yy" from a variable?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dateadd-function)

```vb
Sub Demo()

    Dim s As String, ar, n As Integer
    s = Format(Date, "mmm-yy") ' default
    s = InputBox("mmm-yy", "Input mmm-yy", s)
    ar = PriorYear(s)
    For n = 1 To 12: Debug.Print n, ar(n): Next

End Sub

Function PriorYear(s) As Variant

   Dim ar(1 To 12) As String, dt As Date, n As Integer

   dt = DateValue("01-" & s)
   For n = 12 To 1 Step -1
       dt = DateAdd("m", -1, dt)
       ar(n) = Format(dt, "mmm-yy")
   Next
   PriorYear = ar

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @CDP1802 Straight forward approach +:) fyi you might be interested in my alternative approach posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the more compact version, too:

```
    Dim arr, d As Date: d = Date 'you can choose any date you need
    arr = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & Year(d) - 1 & ",row(" & month(d) & ":" & month(d) + 11 & "),1),""mmm-yy"")"))
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
```

I usually post an answer if OP proves that he tried something by his own and it is good **to learn that this aspect is mandatory in our community**. Even explain in words what you tried. I made an exception only for the challenging sake, since the question has already been answered...

Answer (score 0):

This late post demonstrates how to get the last 12 month dates via `Evaluate`, based on a symbolic formula syntax like

```
{Text(Date(StartYear,Column(StartColumn:EndColumn),1),"mmm-yyyy")}
```

*Extra feature:* The function accepts an optional argument `MonthsCount` changing the default value of *12* last months to any other positive value.

```
Public Function LastNMonths(dt As Date, Optional MonthsCount As Long = 12)
'Purpose: get 1-dim array of last 12 month dates formatted "mmm-yy")
'a) get start date
    Dim StartDate As Date: StartDate = DateAdd("m", -MonthsCount + 1, dt)
    Dim yrs As Long:       yrs = Year(dt) - Year(StartDate)
'b) get column numbers representing months .. e.g. "J:U" or "A:L"
    Dim cols As String
    cols = Split(Cells(, Month(StartDate)).Address, "$")(1)
    cols = cols & ":" & Split(Cells(, Month(dt) + Abs(yrs * 12)).Address, "$")(1)
'c) evaluate dates .. e.g. Text(Date(2020,Column(J:U),1),"mmm-yyyy")
    LastNMonths = Evaluate("Text(Date(" & Year(StartDate) & _
        ",Column(" & cols & "),1),""mmm-yyyy"")")  
End Function
```

**Example call**

You might want to display the resulting "flat" array based on today's date input (ending currently in Sep-2021) within the VB Editor's immediate window by a joined list

```
Debug.Print Join(LastNMonths(Date), "|")
```

returning e.g.

```
Oct-2020|Nov-2020|Dec-2020|Jan-2021|Feb-2021|Mar-2021|Apr-2021|May-2021|Jun-2021|Jul-2021|Aug-2021|Sep-2021
```

Comment: Nice solution. Voted up! I tried posting the most compact configurable one. It is also able to extend the date incremented range if needed. Your code is nice from didactic point of view, too. :)